# How to change template path hints colour and font size

Tags: template

Which file is responsible for the style of magento template path hints?
How can I change the colour and font size of the hints that are highlighted by a red background?

Answer (score 1):

The template path hints are generated in `Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()`.
Unfortunately the styles are hardcoded in the block class and cannot be changed via css.
Because this class is used as a parent class for others you cannot rewrite it in a classical way. You have to cop it in `app/code/local` and do your modifications there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no class or id on those elements. The styles are applied directly to the element. Your only option would be to change the styles using javascript.

You would have to iterate over all div's on the page that have the following CSS properties:

```
position:relative; 
border:1px dotted red; 
margin:6px 2px; 
padding:18px 2px 2px 2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here :
`vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/TemplateEngine/Decorator/DebugHints.php` to change the styles.
If think the best way is to override these class in your theme but i don't know if i's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I created an override to the class Mage_Core_Block_Template by creating a local folder under app > code > local > Mage > Core > Block.
Now I can customize template hints.